# In below code how outer block m gives output 20

Tags: c++

In this code I don't understand how `m` of outer block become `20`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int m=10;

int main()
{
    int m=20;

    {
        int k=m;
        int m=30;
        cout<<"inner block"<<endl;
        cout<<"k="<<k<<endl;
        cout<<"m="<<m<<endl;
        cout<<"::m="<<::m<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"we are in outer block";
    cout<<"m= "<<m<<endl;
    cout<<"::m= "<<::m<<endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean "how it becomes 20 in outer block"? You set it to be equal to 20: `int m=20;`

Comment: m will be redeclear in inner block with 30.so why still in outer surface it give m value 20

Comment: The redeclaration in inner scope is a new variable. It eclipses the one of outer scope. However, the variables of outer scope will be still there and aren't affected by assignments to the variable of inner scope.

Comment: Do you understand that you have three _different_ `m` variables? They're not the same one.

Comment: It has something to do with scope resolution. Since m=20 in the scope where you print the value, it prints 20

Comment: You are declaring m in inner block,so it doesn't exist in outer block. Just instead of (int m = 30), do this (m = 30) then you will understand what happens.

Comment: @ProtapGhosh _You are declaring m in inner block,so it doesn't exist in outer block._ ??? OP declares an `int m` in every scope of the sample.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are the variables which exist only between the curly braces, in which its declared. Outside that they are unavailable and leads to compile time error.If we declare same local variable, outside the scope, it will be having the outside scope value.